# Как вставить картинку вместо надписи на кнопке с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, input, button

Создал такую кнопку:

```
        var deleteButton = document.createElement("input")
        deleteButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
        deleteButton.setAttribute("value", "Delete");
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы кнопкой являлась картинка delete.png

Каким образом это реализовать? Может надо использовать button вместо input?
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deleteButton.src = путь-к-изображению;
deleteButton.type = "image";
document.body.appendChild(deleteButton)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!

Comment: Отлично. Удачи!